# STM32F405 SPI Transmit using DMA not working

Tags: stm32, spi, dma

I have a problem transmitting byte with SPI using DMA and asking for your help to solve this issue.

Used uC: STM32F405RGT6

Target: Display ST7789

Project generated with STM32CubeIDE

Toolchain/IDE: Keil uVision

SPI 2 used/configured as "transmit only, master".

When I'm transmitting in basic blocking mode then everything works fine (but slow):

```
static void ST7789_WriteCommand(uint8_t cmd)
{
   ST7789_DC_Clr();
   HAL_SPI_Transmit(&ST7789_SPI_PORT, &cmd, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
   while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi2) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
}
```

But nothing works when I'm trying to transmit using DMA:

```
static void ST7789_WriteCommand(uint8_t cmd)
{
   ST7789_DC_Clr();
   HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&ST7789_SPI_PORT, &cmd, 1);
   while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi2) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
}
```

Silence on the bus, checked with scope.

HAL_SPI_GetState always returns HAL_SPI_STATE_READY so program does not stuck into while loop waiting for SPI to finish transmitting.

HAL_SPI_ErrorCallback shows 0x10 (HAL_SPI_ERROR_DMA) error in SPI.

**Why this happens, any clues please?**

DMA 1 Initialization (before SPI init):

```
void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Stream4_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream4_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream4_IRQn);

}
```

SPI 2 Initialization:

```
void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */
}

void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* spiHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(spiHandle->Instance==SPI2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_MspInit 0 */
    /* SPI2 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**SPI2 GPIO Configuration
    PC3     ------> SPI2_MOSI
    PB10     ------> SPI2_SCK
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* SPI2 DMA Init */
    /* SPI2_TX Init */
    hdma_spi2_tx.Instance = DMA1_Stream4;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi2_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(spiHandle,hdmatx,hdma_spi2_tx);

    /* SPI2 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI2_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```